# How to get Saturday of a month in Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, date, robotframework

I try to get Saturday of a month.

My Example code:

```
Get day of sat
  ${date}    Get Current Date    result_format=datetime
  FOR    ${INDEX}    IN RANGE    1    10
      ${date}    Add Time To Date    ${date}    1 days    result_format=datetime
      ${dateName}    Convert Date    ${date}    date_format=datetime    result_format=%a
      Exit For Loop If    '${dateName}'=='Sat'
  END
```

But I would like to know how easily way to get the Saturday of a month, Anybody please help?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the robotframework, but here is the javascript that will do the job.

```js
var today = new Date();
var month = today.getMonth();
var year = today.getFullYear();
var first_day = new Date(year,month,1);
var first_sat_day = 1+ (6-first_day.getDay())
console.log("First Saturday Date in current month is : " + first_sat_day)
```

Please feel free to use the part of this is it's helpful.